# How to increase the amount of lines you can read in R's view()

Tags: r

In an RMarkdown file, you can see the below sample text in red. It prints in the console and the RStudio Notebook Output (using `view()`) up to 10,000 lines after running my code.

[image]

However, the total text is 20,000 lines long. I can't find help online which indicates how to increase the number of lines you can view in R and I need to access all of it. Can anyone help? I want to view all of the text basically.

Note that my code took hours to run, RStudio crashed when the code finished executing, and the information I need is saved in red. Hence, I can't re-run the code without the same problem occurring.

Comment: Does `options(max.print = 20000)` solve your problem?

Comment: Potentially - but if I try running this in R Markdown, will it not erase all the text I need? Once it's gone I can't get it back without re-running the R Markdown cell for hours. Or would it work if I run your code in another R Markdown cell before viewing the red text again? @jared_mamrot